# How to change the code Initialization section in mathematica demonstration

Tags: demonstrations

I am designing a mathematica demonstration on video processing and I need to change the **the code Initialization section** in the demonstration to personolize it and put comments about my project. How to do that? What is the utility of this section if we can not edit ? I `click on cell-> editable` but it does not change any thing!
[image]

Comment: See [Initialization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Initialization.html) that is the code that goes into the initialization section of your manipulate. Such as function definitions you use inside Manipulate. That is all what I use it for. If you have no need for initialization section, do not use it.

Comment: ps. You need to make a new cell below that above heading. i.e. do not actually edit the heading shown! Use the mouse, click, and insert new code just below the above description. The code inserted will automatically be in an initialization cell.